# Attribute Error: 'int' object has no attribute 'choice'

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributeerror

I am writing a python program and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Joe\SkyDrive\Documents\Python Project\Python\Forest path.py", line 28, in   <module>
random = random.choice(accuracy)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

Here is a bit of the code it is referring to:

```
while health_1 > 0 and health > 0 and stamina > 0:
    random = random.choice(accuracy)
    if random != "0":
        print("\n\n", random)
        print("\nYou manage to hit the creature for", dmg, "damage!")
        health_1 -= dmg
        stamina -= stam_loss
        print("The creature now has", health_1, "health")
        print("\nThe creature hits you for 1 damage!")
        health -= 1
        print("Health:", health, "Stamina:", stamina,)
```

It does the random module once and then generates the error
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
random = random.choice(accuracy)
```

You are getting an int value in the first iteration and storing it in `random`, which is the module's name. Now, the `random` variable, shadows the `random` module. The best fix would be to use, some other variable name instead of `random`.